# Mysql database restore from rescue mode server

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump

I have one server which is in rescue mode, and limited run the command even the mysqldump. I tried to restore the client database to new server by manually upload and created database but the sql database in phpmyadmin shown the error "#1932 - Table 'xxx' doesn't exist in engine"

I wondering is there any other way restore the database? Very appreciate if someone can solve the problem.